# Filtering through objects with provided values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a json of data and a few checkboxes that should filter out data based on checked items. I googled a lot but I can't wrap my head around this problem. In `data()` I have `checkedFilters: []` which is binded to a few `<input id="someId" value="someValue" v-model="checkedFilters" type="checkbox" />`

Now, I am using `v-for` and iterating through `showFilteredResults`

```
showFilteredResults: function() {
   // Missing: Filter using checkedFilters!
   return this.getCurrentAds; // just returns all ads if no checkbox is selected
}
```

I started to nest `if`s but that leads nowhere. I guess there must be a way to look for matches and filter object accordingly, it's how every webshop works. Can I get a little help and guidance here? I am quite new in the world of Vue and js in general, be kind.

Here is my half-working code

```
this.getCurrentAds.map(ad => {
        Object.values(ad).filter(field => {
          this.checkedFilters.map(filter => {
            if (field === filter) {
              console.log("Match", field);
            }
          });
        });
      });
```

Comment: So... you want to "filter this.getCurrentAds array by some property value" ? if so, what would that property be?

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) might be what you're looking for. Without knowing the structure of the data and what the checkboxes mean, it's difficult to help futher.

Comment: So, you have an array with strings with all the values and an array with the selected filters (also strings). And then, you want to go through these and do what? You need to clarify.

Comment: Checkmarks have a value that corresponds with object values. With active filters, a user should see only matched items.

i.e. cat, short, vaccinated = that's in filters. Only items that match with that criteria should be visible.

Comment: I am trying but I see only errors, I am messing up something with the syntax. Omg, this is horrible.

Comment: So, you want to show all elements, except when there is at least one filter set and then only show this single element? And when there are multiple elements selected, you only want to show those? Then you can just add a `v-if` which checks if there are any filters set. If so, you loop through the filters and if not, you loop through all of them (`v-else`). Usually, you do not have only strings as data but full objects. Then, you cannot just compare them with `===`.

Comment: Okay, that sounds doable but quite repetitive. Wouldn't making a computed property be a better way of handling that?

Comment: Why repetitive? You would only do that once..? Maybe, I don't really understand your problem. Try to explain it in more detail.

Comment: You know how webshops have filters on the left, with color, size and bunch of other things.. I am trying to do the same with my app. I fetched all data but the user will start applying these filters to find what they seek for more easily. With every filter applied I need to go through my fetched data and weed out items that shouldn't be displayed.

`checkedFilters: ["dog"]`

Model has key/value that would be `animalType: dog` so I need to go through values and see if I have a match and then leave that item while ditching all others.

Comment: But are there different filter types or just one array of filters all together? For example is it `filter1: ['dog', 'cat'], filter2: ['milk', 'water']` or `filter: ['dog', 'cat', 'milk', 'water']`?

Comment: Just one array should do it so `["cat", "female", "junior", "New York"]`, but it can be many different combos, I have quite a few fields in my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the clarifications in the comment section, I would do it like below. I assume, that you have an array with data objects. This array is displayed in its entirety when there are no filters in the `filters` array. If there are any filters in it, it will only display the filtered items. There is a computed property which returns always the relevant set of items.

I've added two computed properties which return possible attribute values. So, if there is an `animalType` property in the object, every possible value of this `animalType` is retrieved from the data. This is done with each property for all the data items. Boolean values are filtered out.

When using boolean values, not the value is important but the key. So, similarly to every other property, each key (instead of their values) is returned for booleans.

Those two arrays are then used to filter the effective data. The filtering is still by value (comparison with `===`). So, if you are having an object as an attribute value, this won't work (except it has the same object reference..)

Here is also a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ssc-hrep3/pen/zYOLpQb) to try it out.

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in filteredData">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      data: [{
        name: 'Kitty',
        animalType: 'cat',
        test: 123,
        booleantest: true
      }, {
        name: 'Bello',
        animalType: 'dog'
      }, {
        name: 'Bobby',
        animalType: 'gorilla',
        booleantest: false
      }],
      filters: ['dog', 'booleantest']
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData () {
      return this.data.filter(item => {
        if (this.filters.length === 0) {
          return true;
        }

        let showItem = false;
        this.allObjectPropertiesWithoutBooleans.forEach(property => {
          if (item[property] !== undefined && this.filters.includes(item[property])) {
            showItem = true;
            console.debug(`The item ${JSON.stringify(item)} contains the property "${property}" with the value "${item[property]}" which is also in the filters array.`);
          }
        });
        this.allBooleanObjectProperties.forEach(property => {
          if (item[property] === true && this.filters.includes(property)) {
            showItem = true;
            console.debug(`The item ${JSON.stringify(item)} contains the boolean property "${property}" which is "true" and is also in the filters array.`)
          }
        });
        return showItem;
      });
    },
    allObjectPropertiesWithoutBooleans () {
      const objectProperties = {};
      this.data.forEach(item => {
        Object.keys(item).filter(property => item[property] !== true && item[property] !== false).forEach(property => {
          objectProperties[property] = true;
        });
      });
      return Object.keys(objectProperties);
    },
    allBooleanObjectProperties () {
      const objectProperties = {};
      this.data.forEach(item => {
        Object.keys(item).filter(property => item[property] === true || item[property] === false).forEach(property => {
          objectProperties[property] = true;
        });
      });
      return Object.keys(objectProperties);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: There are many attributes with every object and basically all will be available as filters. This is why I can't crack this.

Comment: Do you have a list of relevant attributes? A list of strings? Or are all object properties relevant? Or all but a list of non-relevant properties (e.g. all but `id`)?

Comment: Or is there a list of attributes to one type of object and a another list of attributes to another type of object which should be checked? You need to clarify.

Comment: filters will contain values that correspond with values found in a model. i.e. 

filters: ["cat", "junior", "vaccinated" ... many more ... ]

model = { animalType: "cat", vaccinated: true, age: "junior" }

Now, it would be great to have some function that would automagically return only items that should be visible based on filters.

Comment: So.. you want to check against every property value by value, except if it is `true`, then check the key? You can build such a logic with `Object.keys(object)` for the keys and `Object.keys(object).map(key => object[key])` for the values (or `Object.values()` if you don't want to support IE).

Comment: I tried to apply this solution but unfortunately, I am getting errors which I can't solve. Thank you for trying, it gave me a new angle to explore further.

Comment: Actually scratch my last answer... It seems it works :D Thank you

Comment: Just btw: it's much more performing, when you know the object structure beforehand and do not have to go through all objects of the data array.